# Error "cannot find Chrome binary" in windows 8 AMD64 while trying to launch selenium web-driver API

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, windows-8, windows-8.1, chrome-web-driver

I'm currently working with Chrome extension of selenium web-driver in windows 8 AMD64. I got an issue launching Chrome; It gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/java/code/SVN/OMC/trunk/Test/Scripts/PMS\elements\UILoader.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 65, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 121, in start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)'
```

I also have put `IEDriverServer.exe` in the same path and it works fine; this path has been added to the system PATH. I also tried to launch it from another computer with windows 7 AMD64 and it works fine there.

I googled a bit and I saw [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=695#c5); but when I checked the path it specified for `chrome.exe`, I couldn't find the executable file for chrome. I tried to update Google Chrome, but it gave me error code 1.

I also tried this:

```
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location(value = "C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = opts)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using `ChromeOptions`; I addressed the chrome's binary file from `ProgramFiles` directory. This is the code I used:

```
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location(value = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = opts)
```

Comment: In my case this code results in TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. As suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085227/1133157, the binary_location is to be assigned directly.

Answer (score 4):

The last line of the error is the important one:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)'

The ChromeDriver has been found, and it is reporting that it cannot find the chrome browser executable. Make sure that is installed and on the current path. Some additional information is on the [Selenium Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver).

Comment: thanks for answer, but I already knew that; as I mentioned, I couldn't find the executable file for chrome. I do't know what is wrong with this application.

Comment: Did you install the Chrome browser on this machine?

Comment: I do not understand. If you cannot find the executable, then how are you using it?

Comment: I did not have Chrome installed on the machine, and installing it fixed the issue. In case anyone sees something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this procedure to install chrome browser on centos and it helped https://sites.google.com/site/imemoryloss/redhat-as-es-centos/install-google-chrome-with-yum-on-fedora-15-14-centos-red-hat-rhel-6

Answer (score 2):

for me it was

```
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location = "path/to/Chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

which fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

you must set the `executable_path` where you install the chrome,this is ruby style.python may be the same in my opinion.

`Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path="D:/Program Files     (x86)/Chrome/chrome.exe"`

Comment: Thanks for response! Yes, I actually used same method in python. You may check my response!